# AJAX: problem with redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the first time ever I'm using AJAX, and I want to do the following on an otherwise static page www.xyz.org/some_site.html:

- Send a GET request to another url `"www.xyz.org/testscript"`
- if response has either `status code != 200` or `content != 'ok'`: do nothing
- else: include sth on the website (i.e. set `style="display:block"` on an element that previously had `"display:none"`)

I've implemented that successfully using basic AJAX. But:

There is an Apache redirect installed pointing from `www.xyz.org/testscript` to `subdomain.xyz.org/testscript`, the URL where the actual testscript lives (as AJAX doesn't support cross-domain calls even to subdomains afaik).

When I call www.xyz.org/testscript I get a `302` status code, and the content says "The document has moved here: subdomain.xyz.org/testscript".

How can I grab the 'final' return value?

I guess/hope any AJAX expert can give me a one-liner to solve that ...

Comment: Most browsers don't allow ajax requests to different domains. As far as I know, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I know. That's why the request is from <code>www.xyz.org/a</code> to <code>www.xyz.org/b</code> ... it's only the redirect that points to a different domain. @Crescent Fresh: Thx for tidying. :)

Comment: @jellybean: you're welcome. Re your question, @sathish is spot on. If your Apache is issuing a redirect, the browser still has to follow the redirect. If the final url is on another [sub]domain you won't be able to perform a standard AJAX request to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX (or XMLHttpRequest to be acurate) won't be tricked by a redirect. To be able to get content from another domain you need to use a proxy on the server. The following is a simple PHP proxy:

```
if(strpos($_GET['q'], "http://") === 0){
  echo file_get_contents($_GET['q']);
}
```

use it like this:

```
xhr.open(GET, "www.xyz.org/proxy.php?q=subdomain.xyz.org/testscript", true);
```

Comment: Make sure you add security before using this script. Otherwise you will find yourself being used for exciting purposes by spammers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, according to the comments above:

It's not possible to achieve what I want to do, as AJAX can't be tricked into following a redirect.

EDIT: I tried to solve it by adding another javascript file at `subdomain.xyz.org/another.js` and throwing all AJAX code from my static html site into it.

Then, on the static html site, I included this script with an ordinary

`<script src="subdomain.xyz.org/another.js">`

tag. But that wouldn't work either ... cheated myself: Including the javascript on my static page results in the original problem again (cross-domain calls forbidden).

Comment: Jellybean, in terms of JavaScript's same-origin policy it is irrelevant which server/domain the included script resides on. The only thing that is important is the domain of the document that includes the script.

Therefore, moving your script to "subdomain.xyz.org" makes no difference, because it is still included in a document from www.xyz.org. But David Flanagan says it better than me: "As part of the same-origin security policy, the XMLHttpRequest object can issue HTTP requests only to the server from which the document that uses it was downloaded." 

Cheers, Tom